# How to remove the all the curly bracket in dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I wish to remove all the curly brackets from my current output. My current output as shown below:

```
 {'Chin PTE LTD': {'Carrot Cake': 22, 'Chocolate Cake': 12, 'Beer': 89}, 'COQ 
SEAFOOD': {'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': 1, 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': 1
}}
```

My current code as shown below:

```
for merchant, product, quantity in big_list:
    d[merchant][product] += quantity

print ({ k:dict(v) for k,v in d.items() })
```

My desired output:

```
'Chin PTE LTD': 'Carrot Cake': 22, 'Chocolate Cake': 12, 'Beer': 89, 'COQ 
    SEAFOOD': 'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': 1, 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': 1
```

As I am still new to python, may I ask if i wish to remove the all the curly brackets in the dictionary of dictionaries. Would my desired output be achievable? If so, how should I go about doing it? Any suggestions / ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First of all why do you want to do that.. And your desired output is it a string or which datastructure you are expecting.

Comment: @AjayPal I want to remove the curly bracket because if presentation purposes. To clarify, my desired output is in a string format. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by converting the dictionary first to a string and then replacing all the brackets with empty strings:

```
d = {'Chin PTE LTD': {'Carrot Cake': 22, 'Chocolate Cake': 12, 'Beer': 89}, 'COQSEAFOOD': {'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': 1, 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': 1}}

print(str(d).replace("{","").replace("}", ""))
```

which will print what you are looking for:

```
'Chin PTE LTD': 'Carrot Cake': 22, 'Chocolate Cake': 12, 'Beer': 89, 'COQSEAFOOD': 'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': 1, 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': 1
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you. =)

Comment: @user3271404 glad to help! Keep in mind dictionaries are not ordered, so if you want that list to always be in the same order, you will need to use a different objet.

Answer (score 0):

Build up the string like so

```
d = {'Chin PTE LTD': {'Carrot Cake': 22, 'Chocolate Cake': 12, 'Beer': 89}, 'COQ SEAFOOD': {'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': 1, 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': 1}}

st = ', '.join('%r: %s' % (k, ', '.join('%r: %r' % (sk, sv) for sk, sv in v.items())) for k, v in d.items())
print(st)
```

This code builds the string by first iterating over the outer dict. It appends the key to the string (plus a ':' in keeping with your formatting requirements). Then it iterates over the inner dict and appends the key and value the same way. It uses the `%r` format specifier which means that the elements being printed are converted using their `repr` function. This gives the strings their quotes, without having to manually add them.

You can't count on the order being fixed though. So for different runs you'll get slightly different orders.

Output looks like

> 'Chin PTE LTD': 'Carrot Cake': 22, 'Chocolate Cake': 12, 'Beer': 89, 'COQ SEAFOOD': 'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': 1, 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': 1

Comment: I don't get how your code works? Do you explaining the logic behind your code? Thank you.

Comment: This will fail if there are more levels of nested dictionaries, as well.

Comment: @enterland Will there be more levels of nested dicts? The question nor the example data mention that. Infact the OPs code shows how the dict is built and its 2 deep.

Comment: @PaulRooney thanks for your kind explanation. I got a clearer picture now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'Chin PTE LTD': {'Carrot Cake': 22, 'Chocolate Cake': 12, 'Beer': 89}, 'COQ SEAFOOD': {'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': 1, 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': 1}}

', '.join(['{}: {}'.format(merchant, ', '.join(['{}: {}'.format(product, quantity) for product, quantity in products.items()])) for merchant, products in d.items()])
```

if you are using python2 instead of python3, replace items with iteritems

Comment: Your solution is cool too.Can I ask what is the difference iteritems and items? Thank you.

Comment: @user3271404 items in python2 builds the complete list at once, but iteritems gives you an iterator.
in python3, items is an [itemview](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)

Comment: got it. Thanks for the explanation. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
result={'Chin PTE LTD': {'Carrot Cake': 22, 'Chocolate Cake': 12, 'Beer': 89}, 'COQ SEAFOOD': {'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': 1, 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': 1}}

expected_output=re.sub("}|{","",str(result))
```